# Unique channels for each 2 users on ActiveCable - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring-websocket

I've been studying ActionCable and spent many hours trying to figure out how it works, and did lot's of researches, but I'm still trying to get satisfactory solutions for me. I have a better understanding now. I managed to subscribe users for a chat and update in real-time, but I don't know what should I do to **create specific channels for each 2 users** (just like a messenger). Should I specify these channels on `stream_from "conversation_channel"` ? And where should I pass the parameters?

**This is the Channel**

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "conversation_channel"
  end
  def unsubscribed
  end
  def speak (data)
    Message.create! content: data["message"]
  end
end
```

**This is the Job**

```
class ConversationBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'conversation_channel', message: render_message(message)
  end

  private
  def render_message(message)
    ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: {message: message})
  end
end
```

**This is the client-side Coffeescript**

```
App.conversation = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ConversationChannel",

  connected: ->
  disconnected: ->
  received: (data) ->
    $('#messages').append data['message']
  speak: (message) ->
    @perform 'speak', message: message

  $(document).on 'keypress', '[data-behavior~=conversation_speaker]', (event) ->
    if event.keyCode is 13
      App.conversation.speak event.target.value
      event.preventDefault()
```

And one last question, is this the path for the ActiveCable to work properly?

`coffeeScript -> Channel -> Model -> Job -> CoffeeScript`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think a little different instead of having a channel for 2 user you may need to use a conversation id, the example here is doing exactly that http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html